# Enable blob cache in sharepoint 2010 foundation

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

> Hi, I have a sharepoint foundation 2010 sp2 version site. for this site i want to enable blob cache. so i want to modify the blobcache  in web.config file. But unfortunately there is no such tag() exists in my web.config file. so how can i enable blob cache for my site.

Answer (score 0):

As the blob cache utilize publishing functionality it is available only in SharePoint Server. :(